# Как перекодировать XML в JSON? Получаю ошибку bool(false) или string(4) "null"

Tags: php, json, xml

Пытаюсь перекодировать xml в json и ничего не получается, онлайн сервисы перекодируют мой xml без проблем, например [этот](https://countwordsfree.com/xmlviewer).

Мой код:

```
<?php

//подгружаю xml файл
$xml = simplexml_load_file('https://accounts.clickbank.com/api2/marketplace');
//перевожу его из xml в json
$json = json_encode($xml);
//формирую массив из json
$data = json_decode($json,TRUE);
//$data = json_encode($jsonString, TRUE);
//проверяю как сформировался массив
var_dump($data);

?>
```

При `$data = json_decode($json,TRUE);` ошибка **bool(false)**

при `$data = json_encode($jsonString, TRUE);` ошибка **string(4) "null"**

Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться.

Comment: Аргумент json_encode должен быть в кодировке utf-8

Comment: [json_last_error_msg()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php)

Comment: utf-8 добавил, не помогло или не так добавил `$json = json_encode($xml, 'UTF-8', true);
`   NULL Еще добавил `header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');`

Comment: `var_dump($xml);`

Comment: var_dump($xml); отдает bool(false)